# Determining a template pack from multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance

Consider this code:

```
enum Brand {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j};

template <Brand, int> struct A {};

struct B : A<a,4>, A<d,0>, A<i,3> {};
struct C : A<b,0>, A<c,5>, A<e,1>, A<h,4>, A<j,0> {};

template <typename, Brand...> void foo() {}

int main() {
    foo<B, a,d,i>();
    foo<C, b,c,e,h,j>();
}
```

`foo<B, a,d,i>();` only makes sense in my (real) program if it has `a,d,i` as parameters, because of B's multiple inheritance.  However, `a,d,i` should be deducible somehow, otherwise there will be maintenance problems if I ever change B's inheritance.  The same thing goes for `foo<C, b,c,e,h,j>();`

I'm stuck writing out `template <typename T> struct GetBrands` to obtain the deducible pack of `Brand` elements from `T`.  Any help would be appreciated.  For now, let's assume the highest int value in A is 10.

Comment: Are the "brand"s guaranteed unique?

Comment: @T.C.  Ah good point.  My algorithm indeed breaks down if they are not unique.  So I don't have a full general solution.  My solution also breaks down miserably if A has more than 2 template parameters.  Which tells me that my solution is quite bad.

Comment: I solved the second issue mentioned above with my new solution, where I introduced a base class of A.  The problem of repeats still remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if we turned the problem on its head and (slightly) changed the way you write the definitions of the `B` and `C` classes?

Below, I've borrowed the test code from your answer:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Brand {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j};

template<Brand, int> struct A { };


template<typename...> struct A_base;
template<Brand... Brands, int... Is> struct A_base<A<Brands, Is>...> : A<Brands, Is>... { };


struct B : A_base<A<a,4>, A<d,0>, A<i,3>> { };
struct C : A_base<A<b,0>, A<c,5>, A<e,1>, A<h,4>, A<j,0>> { };

//template<typename, Brand...> void foo() { }

// *Overloading* foo in order to test the outputs.
template<typename, Brand x, Brand y, Brand z>
void foo() { std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n'; }

template<typename, Brand x, Brand y, Brand z, Brand u, Brand v>
void foo() { std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << ' ' << u << ' ' << v << '\n'; }


template<typename S, Brand... Brands, int... Is> void foo_helper(A_base<A<Brands, Is>...>) 
{ 
    foo<S, Brands...>();
}

template<typename S> void bar() { foo_helper<S>(S()); }


int main()
{
    bar<B>();  // Supposed to be the same as foo<B, a,d,i>();  // 0 3 8
    bar<C>();  // Supposed be the same as foo<C, b,c,e,h,j>();  // 1 2 4 7 9
}
```

I think this can be adapted to handle the more general cases you need.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my second solution to replace the first one.  By introducing a base class of A, I've now allowed the algorithm to work no matter how many template parameters A has (as long as we focus only on the first component of A).  The solution is shorter too now.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

enum Brand {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j, FirstBrand = a, LastBrand = j};

template <Brand> struct HigherBase {};
template <Brand X, int> struct A : HigherBase<X> {};

struct B : A<a,4>, A<d,0>, A<i,3> {};
struct C : A<b,0>, A<c,5>, A<e,1>, A<h,4>, A<j,0> {};

template <typename T, Brand Current, typename Output> struct GetBrandsHelper;

template <typename T, Brand Current, template <Brand...> class P, Brand... Output>
struct GetBrandsHelper<T, Current, P<Output...>> :
    std::conditional<std::is_base_of<HigherBase<Current>, T>::value,
        GetBrandsHelper<T, static_cast<Brand>(Current + 1), P<Output..., Current>>,
        GetBrandsHelper<T, static_cast<Brand>(Current + 1), P<Output...>>
    >::type {};

template <typename Type> struct Identity { using type = Type; };

template <typename T, template <Brand...> class P, Brand... Output>
struct GetBrandsHelper<T, LastBrand, P<Output...>> :
    std::conditional<std::is_base_of<HigherBase<LastBrand>, T>::value,
        Identity<P<Output..., LastBrand>>,
        Identity<P<Output...>>
    >::type {};

template <Brand...> struct FooPack {};

template <typename T>
struct GetBrands : GetBrandsHelper<T, FirstBrand, FooPack<>> {};

//template <typename, Brand...>
//void foo() {}

// Specializing foo in order to test the outputs.
template <typename, Brand x, Brand y, Brand z>
void foo() {std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << '\n';}

template <typename, Brand x, Brand y, Brand z, Brand u, Brand v>
void foo() {std::cout << x << ' ' << y << ' ' << z << ' ' << u << ' ' << v << '\n';}

template <typename T, Brand... Is>
void fooHelper (const FooPack<Is...>&) {
    foo<T, Is...>();
}

template <typename T>
void bar() {
    fooHelper<T> (typename GetBrands<T>::type());
}

int main() {
    bar<B>();  // Supposed to be the same as foo<B, a,d,i>();  // 0 3 8
    bar<C>();  // Supposed be the same as foo<C, b,c,e,h,j>();  // 1 2 4 7 9
}
```

Some generalizations still needed:

1)  What if repeat `Brand` elements are allowed?

2)  What if `A` had N template parameters, and we want to carry out the above for any of the N components?  What would be the general algorithm to handle that in terms of N and the specified component position P (the above solution is the special case of N = 2, P = 0)?  Thus, in the event that we want to carry this out for *all* N components of `A`, we will use the same algorithm but merely change the value of P each time.